# Combine data from two different junction tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Part of my schema is as pictured[image: Category, Items]

I have two junction tables, one of which maps Items to Categories and the second which maps what items are "featured" for a particular category.

What I need to do now is get *all* items that are in a particular category (not difficult), but I also need to have a column "featured" that would display if the item is featured for that category (NULL if not featured).

I've tried various combinations of LEFT JOIN for example

```
SELECT i.*, category.name, category_feat_item.item_id AS featured
FROM item AS i
INNER JOIN item_category ON i.id = item_category.item_id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = item_category.category_id AND category.id =1
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_feat_item ON i.id = category_feat_item.item_id
ORDER BY featured DESC
```

but I'm stumped.

Comment: post what you have tried in codes as well

Comment: select i.*, category.name, category_feat_item.item_id AS featured from item AS i INNER JOIN item_category ON i.id = item_category.item_id 
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = item_category.category_id AND category.id =1
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_feat_item ON i.id = category_feat_item.item_id
ORDER BY featured desc

Comment: kindly edit that in post..same query

Comment: Edited with sample query append

Comment: How do you ensure that featured items are in the `item_category` table?  The featured information should probably be a flag in the `item_category` junction table, rather than a separate table.

Comment: To tell you the truth I hadn't taken that into account...
Your solution would also simplify things considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks almost ok but you need to assign the category_id in the left outer join as well. Otherwise you get all featured items of the item:

```
SELECT i.*, category.name, category_feat_item.item_id AS featured
FROM item AS i
INNER JOIN item_category ON i.id = item_category.item_id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = item_category.category_id AND category.id =1
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_feat_item ON i.id = category_feat_item.item_id AND category_feat_item.category_id = 1
ORDER BY featured DESC
```

Comment: I think you're right.  Might be even better to join on `category.id` and move the `= 1` condition to a `where` clause, so the `1` literal is not repeated twice.

Comment: Or at least use a parameter.